# Java ,int x = 5; System.out.println(" x + 5 is " + x + 5); System.out.println("x += 5 is " + x += 5); why second println is mistake?

Tags: java, operators

Java
int x = 5;

```
    System.out.println(" x + 5 is " + x + 5);//correct
    System.out.println("x += 5 is " + x += 5);// why wrong?
```

Even though, these 2 println is including calculation but why second println is error.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing causes an error because the + is seen as an operator to seperate parts of the string. Try placing that part between brackets like:

```
System.out.println("x += 5 is " + (x += 5));
```

This might fix it as you exclude the + from the string. Hope this helps you a bit, and that I am correct in my statement.

Comment: Adding parentheses is indeed the right solution, but the explanation is wrong. The real reason is that the grammar of Java requires the right-hand argument of `+` to be an MultiplicativeExpression [[spec link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)] rather than an Assignment, so `a + b += c` isn't valid syntax. (This is true regardless of whether `a` is a number or a string.)

Comment: Ah, my bad I should get better at understanding why things work the way they do. Thank you for elaborating the correct reason.

Answer (score 0):

compound assignment operators (such as +=, -=, *=, /=, etc.) cannot be directly used within the println method in Java. The println method expects a single expression or a variable that can be concatenated with strings using the + operator. that's why  x += 5 will be in a block or in bracket.